# Where can I find a working Java EE sample App that connects to a SQL Server database using Native Queries?

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jakarta-ee, orm, hibernate-native-query

Where can I find a working Java EE sample App that connects to a SQL Server database using Native Queries?

I'm using Eclipse, Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), glassfish,

I need to connect a Java EE application in Eclipse to a database in SSMS.

I need an app that specifically calls the SQL Server using native queries, for example "SELECT * FROM Table".

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the information you ask in the following sample:
https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/tree/master/jpa/native-sql

For SQL Server you just need to configure the appropriate datasource and the driver of course.

Here is also a video to help you setup the project:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BB4b-Yz9cF0

Cheers,
Roberto